# Hostname localhost does not include a subdomain in laravel multi tenant application

Tags: laravel

I am a developer and had to run a laravel multi tenant application in localhost xampp. I downloaded all the files using filezilla but when I run the project in localhost then it shows "Hostname localhost does not include a subdomain". I created subdomain on localhost but this problem never solved. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: First of all why are you running Laravel on XAMPP? That is not the best option for a Laravel dev environment. What is the full domain? What is in your hosts file?

Comment: @Gert B https://localhost/vimi/public/ is the domain . Stancl\Tenancy\Exceptions\NotASubdomainException
Hostname localhost does not include a subdomain. This is the error I face. I have  127.0.0.2  vimi.dev in my hosts file and in my httpd-vhosts file I have following code <VirtualHost 127.0.0.2:80>
#DocumentRoot “D:\xampp\htdocs\vimi\public”
#DirectoryIndex index.php
#ServerName vimi.test
#<Directory “D:\xampp\htdocs\vimi\public”>
#Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
#AllowOverride all
#Order Deny,Allow
#Allow from all
#Require all granted
#</Directory>
#</VirtualHost>

Answer (score 0):

if it was a problem related to laravel livewire you could read more [here](https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v3/integrations/livewire/)

and solution would be simple, just include those middleware in case of  **tenant** in **config.livewire.php**
at

```
'middleware_group' => ["web"]
```

to

```
use Stancl\Tenancy\Middleware\PreventAccessFromCentralDomains;

     'middleware_group' => [ 
            'tenant',
            'locale',
            PreventAccessFromCentralDomains::class
    ]
```

and also in case of **central** (universal)
to

```
use Stancl\Tenancy\Middleware\InitializeTenancyByDomain;
    'middleware_group' => [
        'web',
        'universal',
        InitializeTenancyByDomain::class, 
    ],
```

Comment: middleware_group has been removed from livewire 3. Any ideas on how I can resolve a similar issue?.